# React use all useEffects in a seperate component to avoid re-renders

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks

I have a app with React and Redux. I need to do some inits at somewhere on app with useEffect and set values to Redux. Is it *better* to move those useEffects to another component that returns empty(`<></>`) or is there any recommendations how inits like this should be done ?

Normally it was like this:

```
const Main = () => {
  //use redux

  //inits users, current user, history etc.
  useEffect(() => {...}, [...]);
  useEffect(() => {...}, [...]);
  ...

  console.log("main rendered");

  return <>{/*...all components*/}</>;
};
```

`// 'main rendered' text appears on console 3 times`

If I convert above code to something like this:

```
const Main = () => {
  console.log("main rendered");

  return <>
    {/*...all components*/}
    <Init/>
  </>;
};

const Init = () => {
   //use redux

   //inits users, current user, history etc.
   useEffect(() => {...}, [...]);
   useEffect(() => {...}, [...]);
   ... 

  return <></>;
}
```

`// 'main rendered' text appears on console 1 times`

It seemed ok to me but I haven't saw something like this used anywhere, so I wanted to ask is there a catch ?

Answer (score 1):

> Each state change results in rendering.

Consider the component as a function. Something has changed, the function has worked.

Let's analyze the first option:
Install the component **Main**, 2 **useEffect** is + 2 function calls

```
const Main = () => {
  //use redux

  //inits users, current user, history etc.
  useEffect(() => {...}, [...]); // + one
  useEffect(() => {...}, [...]); // + one
  ...

  console.log("main rendered"); // Every change + first render

  return <>{/*...all components*/}</>;
};
```

The second option:
Install the component

```
const Main = () => {
  console.log("main rendered"); // First render

  return <>
    {/*...all components*/}
    <Init/>
  </>;
};

// There is no output here 
const Init = () => {
   //use redux

   //inits users, current user, history etc.
   useEffect(() => {...}, [...]);
   useEffect(() => {...}, [...]);
   ... 

  return <></>;
}
```

2 **useEffects** are called in **Init**. If you write `console.log()` in the **Init** component, you will see the installation and +2 renderers of the component there.

```
const Init = () => {
   //use redux

   //inits users, current user, history etc.
   useEffect(() => {...}, [...]); // + one
   useEffect(() => {...}, [...]); // + one
   ... 
   console.log("Init render"); // first render + re-render
  return <></>;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But the difference is its ok for Init component to re-render because it renders nothing (<></>) but if Main component re-renders it renders all bunch of other components in main return. With Init components it looks more efficient than the first one but I haven't saw something like this before and looks like there might be a better way to do this.

Comment: @WoOHooW Yes, it is more efficient to get the data in the component where they are used. The render of the main component will pull the render of the child components